# Change keyboard input using Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, keyboard, command, prompt

I would like to know whether is it possible to write a batch file that changes the default input language under windows XP What if the language is not installed ? For example, for some reason, My PC always starts with English as a default input language, and every time I have to go to control panel and reset it. I need to write a batch file that, when run, automatically adds french and make it the default one.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly with a batch file, but you could write a simple app that did it and call that from your batch file. There's some useful info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191(VS.85).aspx